# Invalid start action accessing a non isolated expression

Tags: concurrency, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

See the code segment below. I have two variables that are not primitive. `context` is a record, and `keywords` is a `string` array. It shows me the below error. What should be the fix here? I cannot fully understand what the error message tells me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a `start` action within an `isolated` function, the function that is being called has to be an `isolated` function and all of the arguments have to be `isolated` expressions. The errors are because `context` is not final and it is mutable and `keywords` are also mutable.

The solution is to provide `context.clone()` and `keywords.clone()` as arguments, which will create new values and isolate the expressions.

Refer: https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/run-strands-safely-on-separate-threads/